# Testing EJB with embedded container. How can I log in?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-embedded

I'm trying to test my EJBs with the embedded container.

```
container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
```

But I have some of my methods that are restricted to some roles. So, my question is. How can I log into the container so I can test these methods simulating the user that will call the Session Bean ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a post in Oracle blog answering my question to whoever needs as well.

The answer is to use ProgrammaticLogin. You can find more information here.

http://blogs.oracle.com/nithya/entry/running_a_secure_application_using